# adding a module from git url

Tags: node.js, npm

i have a module.which is on private repo.i have git url of it as well https url.but how to add it as dependency.my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.0",
    "jade": "*",
   "passport-strategy" : "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/RiteshM/passport-strategy.git"
  }
}
```

its giving me error on npm install

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-strategy
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-strategy
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: passport-strategy@'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/RiteshM/passport-strategy.git'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-40-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ritesh/projects/passport-topcoder/examples/signin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ritesh/projects/passport-topcoder/examples/signin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

isn't there is any method by which we can install a module without registering it on npm registry ??Please guideline.

Answer (score 3):

Your Git URL is of incorrect format. In the [npm documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html), it is stated that Git URLs must be of one of these formats:

```
git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
```

So your `package.json` should look more like this:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.0",
    "jade": "*",
    "passport-strategy": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/RiteshM/passport-strategy.git"
  }
}
```